# client.get("ping", (err, data) => in redis hangs my node js code

Tags: node.js, redis

This is my server call to route

```
const redis = require("redis");
const client = redis.createClient();
client.connect();
module.exports = client;
```

This is my API route

```
app.get("/api/ping", middleWare.cacheRouteOne, RouteController.routeOne);
```

This is my cache route function

```
exports.cacheRouteOne = (req, res, next) => {
  client.get("ping", (err, data) => {
console.log(data);//To check whether is working or not.
 if (err) throw err;
if (data != null) {
  res.json({
 postss: JSON.parse(data),
 });

} else {
  next();
    }
  });
};
```

And this is my API call code

```
exports.routeOne = (req, res) => {
  axios
    .get("some APi CALL")
    .then((response) => {
      client.setEx("ping", 3600, JSON.stringify(response.data.posts));
      console.log(client);

      res.status(200).json({

        status: true,

        posts: response.data.posts,

      });

    });

};
```

When it calls the middle function it hangs my code after clinet.get()

Comment: Not sure if it's the problem or not, but client.setEx is async and so potentially needs an await.

Comment: Yes, it work, Thank you so much..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the answer, I was making a call back but for forget to add await ,
so this is the updated middleware code

```
exports.cacheRouteOne = async (req, res, next) => {
  let data = await client.get("ping");
  console.log("data of ping");
  if (data != null) { 
    res.json({
      postss: JSON.parse(data),
    });
    console.log("yes");
  } else {
    next();
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

use this code to connect redis

```
const client = redis.createClient({
    socket: {
      port: 6379,
      host: "127.0.0.1",
    }
  });

(async () => {
    // Connect to redis server
    await client.connect();
})();


console.log("Attempting to connect to redis");
client.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected!');
});

// Log any error that may occur to the console
client.on("error", (err) => {
    console.log(`Error:${err}`);
});
```

Comment: did it, in my console its print connected, but still my client.get() hangs my API cals